# Error "Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature" while trying to distribute a Flutter app in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I’m trying to send my build to the store, but when I'm trying to distribute the app with Xcode, I get this error:

> Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature. The provisioning profile included in the bundle 'com.grafenit.velyvelo' (Payload/Runner.app) cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS App Store until it has a valid signature from Apple. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90165 for id 73638f81-3103-4f98-a8f0-d0dd2a01edcc

How can I fix this?

Comment: I got this same error today, but regenerated my distribution certificate and it uploaded fine.

Comment: We're seeing this too, multiple machines and accounts. (Non flutter, all native)

Comment: @Rob How You regenerate the distribution certificate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced this issue this morning.

To fix it,

- Just get Xcode to re-download the provision profiles by deleting everything here: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
- Open *Xcode Preferences*, navigate to *Accounts*, and click *Download Manual Profiles*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me without the second step of "download manual profiles", just removing everything in this folder did the work +1

Answer (score 8):

I got this error on Xcode 13.2 ([macOS v12.2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey)).

It's pretty easy to resolve:

- Go to *Xcode* → *Preferences...*
- On the new window, go to *Accounts* → select your Apple ID
- Then, select your team, click *Manage Certificates*...
- Then, click on *+* on the left bottom, and click *Apple Distribution*
- After that, click *Download Manual Profiles*

You can now *Archive* and it will work fine.

Comment: This finally did it! I spend one hour on it.

Answer (score 5):

I revoked our distribution certificate on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list) and generated a new one. I was then able to upload to App Store Connect again.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:-

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list
2. Open the provision profile
3. Press Edit in the top right
4. Press Save without making any changes This will regenerate the profile with the correct CAs.
5. Now delete the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder and let xcode redownload the profiles again.

This is Work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new distribution certificate through Xcode. I have just done this and it now works.

*Preferences* → *Accounts* → *Choose team* → *Manage certificates* → *+ Apple distribution* → *Archive and upload*.

Answer (score 2):

It has been an error since the Xcode 13.3 (13E113) + [macOS v12.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey) update from Apple.

You need to just regenerate *Provisioning Profile*, without the need to regenerate certificates.

It was resolved as per *[Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature - STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90165](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850186/invalid-provisioning-profile-signature-state-error-validation-error-90165/71853829#71853829)*

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71853883/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an old provisional profile certificate. Just regenerate it again and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue after following these steps:

1. Recreate Distribution Certificate (Make sure it should be Apple
   Distribution).
2. Regenerate Provisioning profile by selecting the new
   Certificate.
3. Open Spotlight, search and delete all Provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
4. Delete all previous Archives from `/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` or you can go to the folder by clicking `Xcode -> Preferences -> Location` and got to the Archive location mentioned there.
5. Delete `Derived Data` by following the same step mentioned above.
6. Clean the Project (Cmd + Shift + k)
7. Archive again, Select the correct Provisioning profile while uploading the build.

Hopefully, this will help.