# Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature - STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90165

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an archive to App Store Connect, and suddenly am getting the following error:

> Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature. The provisioning profile included in the bundle cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS App Store until it has a valid signature from Apple. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90165 for id ...

I am using "Automatically manage signing" and have uploaded an archive just yesterday for the same app with no issue.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature while trying to distribute flutter app in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849897/invalid-provisioning-profile-signature-while-trying-to-distribute-flutter-app-in)

Comment: Later I regenerated the profile and it's working again.. weird.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The issue was caused by two expired Apple certificates<sup>1</sup>.

Solution is to

1. Go to [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list)
2. Open the provision profile
3. Press `Edit` in the top right
4. Press `Save` without making any changes
   This will regenerate the profile with the correct CAs.

Now delete the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder and let xcode redownload the profiles again.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://twitter.com/JI/status/1514043544897425408

Comment: You can put the delete part in bold, because it's the most important one.

Comment: No need to go on the AppStore Connect. This answer works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71856227/8577483

Comment: @Sami no, it only works for auto managed profiles. If you use a manual managed profile you'll need to recreate it manually. Only deleting the folder and redownloading didn't fix the issue for any of our build machines. Recreating them however did.

Answer (score 23):

For me helps:

1. Exit Xcode
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`
3. Execute Xcode and let it rebuild the profiles again.

Answer (score 7):

Apple has updated its WWDR certificates https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/
Some certificates expired in January and some in April of 2022 depending on what version of xCode you had. With that being said, any provisioning profile downloaded before April of 2022 was signed with a now expired WWDR. That's why you'd need to regenerate your provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 5):

Not everyone's certificate can expire at the same time. This may have something to do with apple.

1- Delete All profiles file.
`/Users/X/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

2- Open Xcode and wait 2 second. Xcode can download profiles automatic. You don't need to do anything.

Note that you don't have an expired certificate before that. If there is an expired one, edit it and save it again. will give you a new date.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had been deploying till yesterday. The builds worked fine, all of a sudden today, I started running into this issue as well. Nothing else worked for me. The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Creating a **new** **Apple Distribution Certificate**. (you can follow the steps on the dev portal - developer.apple.com)
2. Download you certificate onto your system
3. you can keep using 'Automatically manage signing'
4. Clean Build Folder
5. Archive
6. Validate
7. Distribute -> Upload worked!

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me.

1. Sign into https://developer.apple.com/.
2. Locate Profiles on the Left Pane
3. Select Profiles and click on the blue + button to Register a New     Provisioning Profile.
4. Under Distribution select App Store.
5. Hit continue on the top right.
6. On the next screen select the apple ID for which this this profile needs to be created.
7. Hit Continue on the top right...
8. Select the certificate to be included with this Profile
9. Hit continue
10. Give the Profile a helpful name and click generate
11. Download it...
12. Once downloaded, double click to install it locally for xcode.
    You should now be able to distribute valid binaries to the app store

Comment: This creates a new certificate, does not resolve the issue, with the existing one. I

Answer (score 3):

Regenerate the Provisioning Profile, you can keep the same certificates.

**Resolve with following steps**

1. Regenerate Provisioning Profiles
   Go to developer.apple.com => Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles => Profiles => click on the profile => Click on EDIT => SAVE again (to ensure it regenerates the Provisioning Profile)
2. Delete locally saved Provisioning file:

   rm -rf ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
3. Then in Xcode accounts, download Profiles again.
   either from Xcode => Preferences => Accounts or
   Runner => Targets => Signing & Capabilities => Prov Profile => Download profiles.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much the same as the already existing one, but your command mentioned at 2) is wrong since it doesn't cover the space in the foldername correctly. This will delete other files if executed like that.

Answer (score 2):

For me, It got resolved when I created the AppStore provisioning profile again and deleted the old one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Solution:-

1. Just get Xcode to re-download the provision profiles by deleting everything here: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
2. Open Xcode Preferences, navigate to Accounts, and click Download Manual Profiles

Answer (score 0):

For those using fastlane, adding force: true to your get_provisioning_profile call will reset the expiration date.

```
get_provisioning_profile( # Create or get provisioning profile
  output_path: "./builds",  # change to whatever works for you
  force: true,
  filename: "AppStore_" + ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"] + ".mobileprovision" # Rename the local provisioning profile
)
```

See: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_provisioning_profile/

Answer (score -1):

```
>     [Getting this error on uploading app on Test Flight. DOn't worry Just follow these steps]
>     [1] Go to Xcode preference
>     [2] Open Accounts tab
>     [3] Click on manage Certificates
>     [4] At bottom 'Apple Distribution Certificates' ,there is your expire certificate. Just delete it and try to upload again 
>     
>     App upload to Test Flight successfully.
>     
>     
>       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjxkg.png
```