# ERROR ITMS-90165: "Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature."

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, publish, testflight

ERROR ITMS-90165: "Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature. The provisioning profile included in the bundle 'com.xxxx.xxxx.qa' (Payload/Runner.app) cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS App Store until it has a valid signature from Apple. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

I got this error, when I was trying to add my app for review.
How can I handle with this? Everything was okay till yesterday

I handle with this issue like that =>

1. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
2. Open profile,
   Press Edit in the top right,
   Press Save without making any changes
3. Delete the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder (if you cannt find press (command+shift+'.') because this is hidden folder)
4. restart xcode

Comment: do you check the provisioning expiration?

Comment: Hi Lala, I have the same issue and opened a case at Apple. All my certificates are okay, so they will send me a questionnaire to further dig into this. They can't pinpoint the error right away. I keep you posted.

Comment: Okay, Im waiting good news from you :)

Comment: I am getting the similar error since yesterday evening soo I'd love to know as well!

Comment: Someone on the Fastlane repository said to regenerate all profiles, so I'm going to try that first; https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20164

Comment: I do also encounter this and having now a hard time

Comment: I got word back from Apple support. I don't know what they did, since there was nothing expired on my side. Today I received an email to try validate and upload a build again. This worked. My app is now waiting for review.

Answer (score 5):

A quote from James Ide (Expo):

> Two Apple certificates used to sign your provisioning profiles expired today. When you try to submit your app for review you'll get an ITMS-90165 error. Fix is to get a new provisioning profile.

> The provisioning profile is signed by a chain of three certificates. openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -in embedded.mobileprovision -inform der
> These are different from your code signing certificate. The root CA in the chain is fine but the two children expired April 12, 2022.

See: https://twitter.com/JI/status/1514043544897425408

Comment: i tried removing my provisiong profile and create new one but no luck so after that i go to my xcode then preferences , accounts create new manage profile and add another apple distribution and from that it work for me.

Comment: There are several ways of creating new provisioning profiles so I'm happy that works for you. I manage all my profiles through fastlane and that was just super easy to nuke and match.

Answer (score 3):

For me in my case

what i did is i go to my Xcode

-> Preferences

-> Accounts Select your App ID's

-> then what i did is clicking manage certificate

-> then a dialog will show so next  click plus button

-> then click Apple Distribution then Done

i tried to upload again and it work for me.
For some reason, as i follow above deleting or remove provisioning profile. I quite regret it and i created new one but what done is done , so as long as it work.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with comas and dots

Answer (score 1):

Follow these 2 steps this issue will solved.
Delete all PP from this path ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Open Xcode Preferences then navigate to Accounts and click Download Manual Profiles. Then upload build, issue will fixed.

Answer (score -1):

No need to create any new profile, just edit the existing profile (this is known issue with XCode 13.2)

1. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles Open the provision
   profile
2. Press Edit in the top right Press Save without making any
   changes This will regenerate the profile with the correct CAs.
3. delete the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder and
   let xcode redownload the profiles again.

Comment: Likely copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853423 . Please credit sources.